# Rings without any form of division, at all?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A unital commutative ring is a field where "division is not necessarily possible".

Example. In $\mathbb{Z}$ we can divide $20$ by $4$, but not by $9$. (In general, divisibility of integers $a$ and $b$ depends on the ideals $(a)$ and $(b)$, I think, which may or may not be related to the prime factorization of $a$ and $b$.)

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_(ring_theory)), divisibility is equivalent to containment of ideals, in the sense that:

$$a|b \Longleftrightarrow (b)\subseteq(a).$$

(I assume "$\subseteq$" simply means "subset", and not "subring", or something more demanding.)

I wonder if there's a nontrivial ring $R$ where division is *never* possible (other than by the multiplicative identity), ie. it's *never* true that $a|b$ (unless $a$ is $1$)? I think this would mean that no ideal is a subset of any other ideal (other than itself, and all of $R$).

Comment: What about simple rings with no proper ideals?

Comment: It's always true that $(ab) \subseteq (a)$.

Comment: You always have $a|a$ and $a|0$.

Comment: BTW, I think you are trying to talk about "the notion of division is trivial", which is a *very* different idea from "there is no form of division".

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, I meant that division is trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is an example, and isn't (quite) trivial! Similarly, for any $n$ the ring $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$ is an example, and we can get infinite rings with no nontrivial division in the same way.

What else can we say?

First, a quick observation about divisibility of elements versus containment of ideals: note that you can have distinct elements which generate the same ideal. So, while the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain, it *does* have nontrivial division since for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a=(-a)(-1)$ and hence $-1\vert a$.

More generally, we get nontrivial division in any ring with *any nontrivial unit*. In particular, since $(-1)(-1)=1$ in every ring, we must have $-1=1$, and more generally for all $x$ we have $-x=x$ - our ring has characteristic $2$. Moreover, for any $x$ we have $x\vert x^2$, so we need to always have $x^2=0$ or $x^2=x$ to avoid a nontrivial instance of division.

With this in mind, we can cook up another ring with no nontrivial division, distinct from those of the first paragraph. Here's a natural first guess: our ring has elements $0, 1, a, 1+a$, and addition and multiplication are given in the obvious way together with the rules that:

- $1+1=a+a=0$, and
- $a\cdot a=0$.

Can you come up with more?

Comment: This is very insightful, thank you. Although I'm starting to think that perhaps I meant "no division by anything other than the units", since in any rings every unit divides everything. This makes $-1|a$ also trivial, since $-1$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$, and trivially divides everything